# Select last element before my current element that has one class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I want to select with jQuery the last element that it has `pu` class before the element with which I launch this event knowing that I there are a lots of elements before and after the current that have this class

Here is an example :

```
<div class="pu" ></div>
<div class="pu" ></div>
<div class="pu" ></div>
<div class="current" ondragenter="myfunction();" ></div>
<div class="pu" ></div>
<div class="pu" ></div>
```

for this example, I want to select the last element that has `pu` class before the div that has current class when the `ondragenter` is launched.

I have this case because the `div` are generated from server side

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are all your inputs wrapped? and they have these classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take care of selection even-though your immediate previous element to `current` does not have the `pu` class.

**http://jsfiddle.net/2Vunz/**

[PrevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```
$('div.current').prevAll('div.pu:first');
```

This will take care of any wrappers.

**http://jsfiddle.net/S2LfA/**

```
$('input.current').parent().prevAll().find('input.pu').eq(0)
```

Comment: I m inspired by your solution : here is the solution : $(this).parent().find('.pu')

Answer (score 2):

The following line of jQuery will select the previous sibling elements of `div.current` based on the selector `div.pu`:

```
$('div.current').prevAll('div.pu:first');
```

"Previous sibling elements" and that selector signify that this will get you the `pu` class `div` right before the `current` class `div`, assuming they are on the same level of the DOM like in your example.

Comment: thank you, but in my example, they are not in the same level, maybe each one is included in another div

Comment: here is the right situation, I don't have div but I have input and each one is included in `<td>`

Comment: Are they all in a separate `<td>` element?

Comment: Looks like PSCoder has the solution, if I am understanding correctly. GJ!

Comment: Hmm @Michal seems like this is what he is looking for... But not sure!!

Answer (score -2):

try this code:

```
$('div.pu:last')
```